# Are there some viruses that write assembly code instead of machine code, and use an external assembler?

Tags: virus, antivirus, false-alarm

Like the question says, I am wondering if there are some viruses that do not write machine code themselves, but instead output assembly code and invoke an external assembler? That sounds like a plausible attack on Linux systems, where `as` (GNU Assembler) is usually present in the `PATH`.

I know that assemblers and linkers often get misdetected as viruses because they, like viruses, write executable files. However, I am stunned that Microsoft Windows Defender once [misdetected](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/ArithmeticExpressionCompiler/issues/3) the compiler for my programming language as malware. But the compiler for my programming language outputs assembly code, and not machine code. So how could it possibly be mistaken for malware?

Comment: How do you know defender flagged it malicious for outputting assembly code and not something else?

Comment: @yeah_well I don't. How can I determine that?

Comment: try this for starters https://github.com/matterpreter/DefenderCheck